# SMIL "begin" and "end" animation attriubutes not called in Chrome but called in Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, svg, smil

```
<ellipse cx="150" cy="75" rx="10" ry="40" fill="blue">
<animate id="A" attributeName="rx" begin="click"
end="A.begin+4"
onbegin="alert('started')" onend="alert('stopped')"
dur="4s" values="10;110;10" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</ellipse>
```

The above code works as expected in Firefox but not in Chrome. 
In Firefox alerts are shown in the begining and in the end of the animation. 
How can I achieve that in Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have write a patch for [bug 81995](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=81995) or pay someone else to do it for you to get this to work in webkit.

Comment: Thank you... I suspected it was a bug.